# Node converting relative path to absolute, not desired

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following issue, in the function sendDownload(downlodable ,objPathArray, responseObject) I am receiving the parameter objPathArray like this:

```
[{"pathToFile":"./REPORTS/portfolio/onDemand/Portfolio_report_HP_17.08.2021.xlsx","file":"Portfolio_report_HP_17.08.2021.xlsx"}]
```

The function:

```
function sendDownload(downlodable ,objPathArray, responseObject) {    
    if (downlodable) {  
        responseObject.download((objPathArray[0].pathToFile), (objPathArray[0].file))      
        console.log('HERE ' + JSON.stringify(objPathArray))        
    }
}
```

but when I call the function in my app I receive this error `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Work\reporting-server\REPORTS\portfolio\onDemand\Portfolio_report_HP_17.08.2021.xlsx'` and that's because Node is changing my relative path for the file in an absolute one.
What is the best option for me in order to solve this issue ?

Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

Node.js **must** resolve the path to find the file.

If you give it a relative path then it has to start **somewhere** and that somewhere is the current working directory.

If you want it to read the file from somewhere else then resolve it to an absolute path yourself.

Generally speaking the tools to do this will be [`path.resolve`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths) and something to tell it where to start from such as [a configuration file](https://www.npmjs.com/package//config), [environment variable](https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-read-environment-variables-from-nodejs), or [the directory the module is in](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname).

Comment: Ok, thhank you! I'll pass a path instance as parameter to my function and I'll let you know if works

Comment: Well.. is not that. I have refactored the function like this
function sendDownload(downlodable, objPathArray, pathInstance, responseObject) {
    // objPathArray = [{"pathToFile":"./REPORTS/portfolio/onDemand/Portfolio_report_HP_17.08.2021.xlsx","file":"Portfolio_report_HP_17.08.2021.xlsx"}]
    if (downlodable) {       responseObject.download(pathInstance.join(pathInstance.dirname(objPathArray[0].pathToFile),objPathArray[0].file))        
    }
}

And ...I got the same error, the path is correct, the file is there, I also left the file in place from the last call, and still not get it